# HTTP request GET response showing NULL value

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, nsurlconnection

I want to create `HTTP` request `post` and `get` response by using simple Objective C Code method. Here below code to I can post successfully. But I didn't receive response data's. Response printing  `null` value only. Please help me, I need to get response data's.

Here below my code

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@",name];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:URLPATH]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if(conn) {
      NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
} else {
      NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
}



// Create GET method
NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *responser;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responser error:&err];

// JSON Formatter
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *jsonsDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSDictionary *respon = [jsonsDictionary objectForKey:@"response"];
NSLog(@"UPDATE RESPONSE : %@", respon);
```

Comment: The response is not valid JSON. Create NSString from responseData and print that out. Also print the err and error variables.

Comment: Could you please post some code? I can't get you.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", err); and NSLog(@"%@", error);

Comment: Printing (null) only @AbhiBeckert

Comment: Please update your question to show exactly what you did and which one gives what output.

Comment: But if i print directly responseData then I can receive mechinecodes...

Comment: OK good, that means you're getting some data back from the server, so the HTTP Request is working flawlessly. Your problem is decoding the response as JSON. You need to find out what is in the data. Use a tool such as HexFiend to convert the raw data into human readable text. http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/

Comment: that's right...Do you have any data converstion Code sample. Please post it.@AbhiBeckert

Comment: How about do a google search instead for how to convert NSData to NSString? It might not be possible anyway, because the data might not be a valid string. That's why I suggested using HexFiend instead.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple:

```
//-- Convert string into URL
    NSString *jsonUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"demo.com/your_server_db_name/service/link"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[jsonUrlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //-- Send request to server
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
    //-- Send username & password for url authorization
    [request setValue: jsonUrlString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; //-- Request method GET/POST

    //-- Receive response from server
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    //-- JSON Parsing with response data
    NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Result = %@",result);
```

Sample : https://github.com/svmrajesh/Json-Sample

Comment: Why post this when there are already hundreds of examples of how to  convert JSON to an Objective-C collection already on this site?

Comment: what is the authValue?

Comment: Don't use this code, I can see a bunch of bugs in it. Your code doesn't have any bugs, you just need to find out what data the server is responding with. It's returning an invalid response.

Answer (score 0):

You's data post is `NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@",name];` . So in this case you need set request header `"Content-Type"` to `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`  or use following code to convert string to data and set Content-Type header:

```
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
 ...
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Comment: The request headers might not be needed. It depends on what the server expects, some will ignore the Content-Type header. He is getting a response from the server and needs to make the code handle that.

Comment: I don't think it is not need in this case. Because it content body data format info

Comment: Try use this code I did post. Use NSUTF8StringEncoding instead of NSASCIIStringEncoding, and set "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" for request header field "Content-Type". @Mano